# How to check "Help improve Ubuntu" option state on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I totally forgot what was selected on started "Help improve Ubuntu" screen (Yes, send system info to Canonical / No, don't send system info).
How can I check state of that option?
May be it stored in some setting file, that can viewed by 'cat' command etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out is to open the Terminal app (press <kbd>Super</kbd>, type 'Terminal', and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and enter the following command:

```
ubuntu-report interactive
```

In my case, since I did opt-in, entering that command gives the following message:

```
ERRO metrics from this machine have already been reported and can be found in: /home/johnkizer/.cache/ubuntu-report/ubuntu.23.10
```

But, if you hadn't, that command will prompt you to collect, review and send the information.

Here's the link to the code and README for the data collection tool: https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-report

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I made some research with VirtualBox. Found out that if "send system info" was accepted file on path <home>/.cache/ubuntu-report/pending will be contain sended report. But if "send system info" was declined, "pending" file will be contain one line - {"OptOut": true}